# Tool to check speed of the page of multiple URL's at same time

Tags: load-testing

I want a tool which will give me the loading speed of multiple urls from same tool with one search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this:

http://www.webpagetest.org/video/

could maybe help you.

Comment: Wow... This is great for Web Vitals... Before web vitals like reflow time were a thing. I was just using as a blunt filter while cross shopping

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for free (and open source) solution there is quite a list at http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php

The most promising and powerful of them imho are:

- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)

See [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) guide which highlights main features and sample load reports followed by comparison matrix